# How to connect to a minikube cluster from a docker container?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube, kubeconfig

I have a running `minikube` cluster. I can easily connect to it and apply changes using `kubectl`. But I want to run `kubectl` from a docker container. Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk --no-cache add curl

# Install and configure kubectl
RUN curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/release/$(curl -L -s https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl"
RUN mkdir -p ~/.local/bin/kubectl
RUN mv ./kubectl ~/.local/bin/kubectl
RUN chmod +x ~/.local/bin/kubectl/ -R
```

It's basically a simple `alpine` image with `kubectl` installed.

How can I connect to my `minikube` cluster from this container?

Comment: Can you run the container inside Kubernetes instead, using a ServiceAccount and an associated RoleBinding to get permissions to modify things?

Comment: Mount your `.kube` folder into the container at the same place (`-v ~/.kube:~/.kube`). Then you'll have access to your kube config.

Comment: @DavidMaze I don't know! But I have thought about it too. That way, CI/CD pipelines would be much easier and more optimized. But I believe it didn't relate to my question. It's another question you might wanna ask and let me know about it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to copy `~/.kube` and `~/.minikube` folders into the image. This is the new Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk --no-cache add curl

# Install and configure kubectl
RUN curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/release/$(curl -L -s https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl"
RUN mkdir -p ~/.local/bin/kubectl
RUN mv ./kubectl ~/.local/bin/kubectl
COPY .kube /root/.kube
COPY .minikube /root/.minikube
RUN chmod +r ~/.kube/config
RUN chmod +x ~/.local/bin/kubectl/ -R
WORKDIR /root/.local/bin/kubectl/
```

You can use the image like this:

```
docker build . -t USERNAME/kubectl:latest
docker run USERNAME/kubectl:latest ./kubectl get pods
```

***ATTENTION***

The `.kube/config` file is created for the host system. So you need to change some paths in `.kube/config` file to point to the `.minikube` folder in the container.

***ALSO NOTE THAT***

`~/.minikube` and `~/.kube` are huge folders. Adding them to your docker build context could make your builds really slow.

You might want to mount volumes for that purpose.